# How to STORE into a file where the name is defined in the Tuple?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Let's say I have have the following example code:

```
USERS = LOAD 'Users' AS (location, name, age, date);
STORE USERS INTO '**%location%**-records.json' USING JsonStorage();
```

I want to store the records for a given location in the data into a specific file. I can't find anything that would suggest Pig can do this but I'm optimistic that it can?

Answer (score 0):

as of my knowledge we cant do it with pig variables. i am pointing one approach.maybe this would useful.

```
USERS = LOAD 'Users' AS (location, name, age, date);

SPLIT USERS INTO
location1 IF location matches 'location1',
location2 IF location matches 'location2',
location3 IF (location matches 'location3')
;

STORE location1 INTO 'location1-records.json' USING JsonStorage();
STORE location2 INTO 'location2-records.json' USING JsonStorage();
STORE location3 INTO 'location3-records.json' USING JsonStorage();
```